# TYPO3 "Verifying Login Data" endless loop

Tags: typo3

I am struggling with login into my TYPO3 Backend.
After solving some issues with cache files that could not be written, I am now unable to login due to an endless loop after clicking on the login button.

I am working on a Windows 2008 Server. I am using Plesk and IIS. 
I really don't know why this happens...

**What i have done so far:**

- I've installed openSSL on the server
- I tried to edit the LocalConfiguration.php adding the path to my openssl.exe
- deleted all (db + files) and reinstalled it again

**ERROR MESSAGE**

> No OpenSSL backend could be obtained for rsaauth.

Would be very nice if someone could give me some advices to perhaps solve my problem!

Comment: You need to install the PHP extension `openssl`, not openssl itself. Usually it's bundled with PHP, but on Windows it needs to be enabled in your `php.ini`.

Comment: In previous installations I needed an environment variable that pointed to the OpenSSL configuration file. Press _WIN + Break_ , select _Advanced system settings_, press the _Environment variables..._ button and add the _System variable_ "OPENSSL_CONF" and as value the path to the `openssl.conf` file. Unfortunately you have to restart before the variable is available.
I still have it and OpenSSL works without a problem here.

Comment: hey, thank you for answering. So, I if i don't need to install openssl itself, do i have to add the openssl.conf of the extension to the system variables then? And can you maybe tell me the extension key of openssl? if i just search for openssl it doesn't find anything